# Why is my resource file text being translated when displayed in browser?

Tags: c#, resources, lang

I have 3 resource files in my project.  One for English, one for French Canadian (fr-CA) and one for Spanish (es).  In my English resource file I have the sentence: Added transparency and trust in their media transactions  In the Spanish resource file the sentence is: Mayor transparencia y confianza en sus transacciones con medios.  When the text is displayed in the browser with the language set to Spanish it displays as Anadido transparencia y confianza en sus transacciones con medios.  Mayor was changed to Anadido.  The French translation that is displayed has different sentences not just words.  In the French Canadian resource file the sentence is: une transparence et une confiance accrues à l’égard des transactions-médias.  This is what is displayed: Ajout de transparence et de confiance dans leurs transactions multimedias.

This is occurring in Chrome.  I haven't checked other browsers yet.

Comment: Chrome has an auto translate ability .. not always accurate

Comment: So even though I have the resource file set up, it's doing an auto translate?

Comment: it does seem odd but it would appear so.  There doesnt sound like any other excuse for it, its not like its sending english when you asked for spanish its sending the spanish but changing it, almost like it converts it to say english and then back to spanish

Comment: These are the *exact* phrases that Google Translate generates, just try it.  So your resources are not being used, nobody can guess why.